# How to get the view or component object using its name in Vue js?

Tags: javascript, mvvm, viewmodel, vue.js

Javascript code:

```
    var main = new Vue({ 
        el: "#main", 
        data: { 
            currentView: "top", 
        }, 
    }); 

   var topComponent = Vue.component('top', Vue.extend({ 
    template: "#top", 
   }));
```

Now when I access main.currentView, I get "top". But with this string 'top', how do i get the component `topComponent`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [DOM element to corresponding vue.js component](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26915193/dom-element-to-corresponding-vue-js-component)

Answer (score 13):

From the [VueJS guide](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Child-Component-Refs)

> Despite the existence of props and events, sometimes you might still need to directly access a child component in JavaScript. To achieve this you have to assign a reference ID to the child component using `ref`. For example:

```js
var parent = new Vue({ el: '#parent' })
// access child component instance
var child = parent.$refs.profile
```

```html
<div id="parent">
     <user-profile ref="profile"></user-profile>
</div>
```

Comment: What about accessing child of third-party component?

Comment: is isn't global

Answer (score 8):

It's easy. You can access the `topComponent` just using `Vue.component`.

```
var topComponent = Vue.component('top');
```

Now you have `topComponent`, you can do a lot of things with its methods.

```
cid
options
super
extend
directive
filter
partial
transition
component
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check out this example:

http://jsbin.com/wikeb/1/edit

It uses the [v-view](http://vuejs.org/api/directives.html#v-view) directive in the html, which takes a string to change the viewmodel displayed. Some sweet transitions going on as well.

Comes from: https://github.com/yyx990803/vue/blob/master/test/functional/fixtures/routing.html

Comment: this exemple works for the old legacy version of vue.
I corrected it and here is the update http://jsbin.com/jizegefape/2/