# DOM element to corresponding vue.js component

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, vue.js, dom

How can I find the vue.js component corresponding to a DOM element?

If I have

```
element = document.getElementById(id);
```

Is there a vue method equivalent to the jQuery

```
$(element)
```

Comment: There is no way to do that as far as I know.

Comment: Do you mind accepting my answer?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

The proper way to do with would be to use the `v-el` directive to give it a reference. Then you can do `this.$$[reference]`.

### Update for vue 2

In Vue 2 refs are used for both elements and components: http://vuejs.org/guide/migration.html#v-el-and-v-ref-replaced

Comment: In Vue 2, the `v-el` directive seems not to be there anymore.

Comment: In Vue 2 I added `ref="myid"` to the elements but had to reference it in JavaScript with `this.$refs["myid"]`.

Comment: A cool thing about ref is that it can be dynamically defined: 
`:ref="'item' + item.id"`. However, this will seldom be neccesary because refs defined in loops automatically gets gets into an array this.$refs['combo-inside-loop'][index]

Answer (score 79):

Just by this (in your method in "methods"):

```
element = this.$el;
```

:)

Comment: This is not what the question asks. The question is if you have a reference to a node, how can you get a reference to the Vue component that rendered it, not what's the root element of the component. If you are in the `methods` you already have a reference to the component via `this`.

Comment: The Question title deceived me - but because some persons (also deceived by question title) find answer here I will left this answer.

Comment: Hint for others: After rendering, in my environment with Vue 1.x, `this.$el`is just an HTML comment object, not even the root object.

Comment: make sure you depend on this at least after `mounted()`. for example on `created()` this is `undefined`

Answer (score 55):

In Vue.js 2 Inside a Vue Instance **or** Component:

- Use `this.$el` to get the HTMLElement the instance/component was mounted to

From an **`HTMLElement`**:

- Use `.__vue__` from the HTMLElement

  - E.g. `var vueInstance = document.getElementById('app').__vue__;`

Having a `VNode` in a variable called `vnode` you can:

- use `vnode.elm` to get the element that VNode was rendered to
- use `vnode.context` to get the **VueComponent** instance that VNode's component was declared (this usually returns the parent component, but may surprise you when using [slots](https://jsfiddle.net/acdcjunior/9emvr5az/2/).
- use `vnode.componentInstance` to get the **Actual VueComponent** instance that VNode is about

Source, literally: [**vue/flow/vnode.js**](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/11614d63b7862b68b11cc45c0891437c62a832d7/flow/vnode.js#L11-L33).

## Runnable Demo:

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = false; // disable developer version warning
console.log('-------------------')

Vue.component('my-component', {
  template: `<input>`,
  mounted: function() {
    console.log('[my-component] is mounted at element:', this.$el);
  }
});

Vue.directive('customdirective', {
  bind: function (el, binding, vnode) {
    console.log('[DIRECTIVE] My Element is:', vnode.elm);
    console.log('[DIRECTIVE] My componentInstance is:', vnode.componentInstance);
    console.log('[DIRECTIVE] My context is:', vnode.context);
    // some properties, such as $el, may take an extra tick to be set, thus you need to...
    Vue.nextTick(() => console.log('[DIRECTIVE][AFTER TICK] My context is:', vnode.context.$el))
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  mounted: function() {
    console.log('[ROOT] This Vue instance is mounted at element:', this.$el);
    
    console.log('[ROOT] From the element to the Vue instance:', document.getElementById('app').__vue__);
    console.log('[ROOT] Vue component instance of my-component:', document.querySelector('input').__vue__);
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.15/dist/vue.min.js"></script>

<h1>Open the browser's console</h1>
<div id="app">
  <my-component v-customdirective=""></my-component>
</div>
```

Comment: https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/dev/src/core/instance/lifecycle.js

Given a "Vue" _instance_ **vm**:
`vm._vnode = vnode`


With that, you can cross-walk the DOM Node tree, the VNode (VDOM) tree and the Vue tree.

Comment: where is `vnode.elm` documented?

Comment: what's the difference between **vnode.context** and **vnode.componentInstance**

Comment: @Archsx `context` is the Vue instance (the root component). `componentInstance` is the component instance (may or may not be the root component. It won't be the root component if it is an instance of a custom component you created -- via `Vue.component('my-comp', { ...})`, for instance).

Comment: @acdcjunior  let me put it this way,  imagine we have a ```Root.vue file```,and its template is ```<Parent><Child v-custom-directive><Child></Parent>``` so ```vnode.context``` is the ```Root component``` instance ,and ```vnode.componentInstance``` is ```Child component``` instance ? right ?

Comment: @Archsx actually, in your example, the `context` seems to be the parent component (not the root component). I have update the answer to make it clearer. See if this fiddle helps you: https://jsfiddle.net/acdcjunior/ukweftav/ let me know!

Comment: @acdcjunior thanks a lot ! but what I actually means is https://jsfiddle.net/s7jem8oa/ so I think **"Parent Component"** may make me confused, thinking about slots.

Comment: @Archsx perhaps `vnode.context.$el` (https://jsfiddle.net/acdcjunior/9emvr5az/2/) is of use to you. It appears that `vnode.context` points to the element the component was *declared* in. In the case of that fiddle, the `<Child>` is declared in the root ("slotted" into `<Parent>`)

Answer (score 15):

If you're starting with a DOM element, check for a `__vue__` property on that element. Any Vue View Models (components, VMs created by `v-repeat` usage) will have this property.

You can use the "Inspect Element" feature in your browsers developer console (at least in Firefox and Chrome) to view the DOM properties.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Pro tip: Find the element in "Elements" tab of Developer Console, select that, and then type `c = $0.__vue__` in console.  Now `c` is your Vue component and you can inspect all its properties. :)

Answer (score 8):

- `this.$el` - points to the root element of the component
- `this.$refs.<ref name>` + `<div ref="<ref name>" ...` - points to nested element

> use `$el`/`$refs` only after `mounted()` step of [vue lifecycle](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Lifecycle-Diagram)

```
<template>
    <div>
        root element
        <div ref="childElement">child element</div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        mounted() {
            let rootElement = this.$el;
            let childElement = this.$refs.childElement;

            console.log(rootElement);
            console.log(childElement);
        }
    }
</script>

<style scoped>
</style>
```

> [image]

Answer (score 6):

Since v-ref is no longer a directive, but a special attribute, it can also be dynamically defined. This is especially useful in combination with v-for.

For example:

```
<ul>
    <li v-for="(item, key) in items" v-on:click="play(item,$event)">
        <a v-bind:ref="'key' + item.id" v-bind:href="item.url">
            <!-- content -->
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

and in Vue component you can use

```
var recordingModel = new Vue({
  el:'#rec-container',
  data:{
    items:[]
  },

  methods:{
    play:function(item,e){
      // it contains the bound reference
      console.log(this.$refs['key'+item.id]);
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 6):

So I figured `$0.__vue__` doesn't work very well with HOCs (high order components).

```html
// ListItem.vue
<template>
    <vm-product-item/>
<template>
```

From the template above, if you have `ListItem` component, that has `ProductItem` as it's root, and you try `$0.__vue__` in console the result unexpectedly would be the `ListItem` instance.

Here I got a solution to select the lowest level component (`ProductItem` in this case).

### Plugin

```js
// DomNodeToComponent.js
export default {
  install: (Vue, options) => {
    Vue.mixin({
      mounted () {
        this.$el.__vueComponent__ = this
      },
    })
  },
}
```

### Install

```js
import DomNodeToComponent from'./plugins/DomNodeToComponent/DomNodeToComponent'
Vue.use(DomNodeToComponent)
```

### Use

- In browser console click on dom element.
- Type `$0.__vueComponent__`.
- Do whatever you want with component. Access data. Do changes. Run exposed methods from e2e.

### Bonus feature

If you want more, you can just use `$0.__vue__.$parent`. Meaning if 3 components share the same dom node, you'll have to write `$0.__vue__.$parent.$parent` to get the main component. This approach is less laconic, but gives better control.

Answer (score 1):

I found this snippet [here](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/dom-element-to-vue-component/7617/2). The idea is to go up the DOM node hierarchy until a `__vue__` property is found.

```
function getVueFromElement(el) {
  while (el) {
    if (el.__vue__) {
      return el.__vue__
    } else {
      el = el.parentNode
    }
  }
}
```

In Chrome:

[image: Usage in Chrome]

Answer (score 0):

## Solution for Vue 3

I needed to create a navbar and collapse the menu item when clicked outside. I created a click listener on windows in `mounted` life cycle hook as follows

```
mounted() {
    window.addEventListener('click', (e)=>{
        if(e.target !== this.$el)
            this.showChild = false;
    })
}
```

You can also check if the element is child of this.$el. However, in my case the children were all links and this didn't matter much.

Answer (score -2):

If you want listen an event (i.e OnClick) on an input with "demo" id, you can use:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data: {
    n: 0
  },
  methods: {
   onClick: function (e) {
     console.log(e.target.tagName) // "A"
     console.log(e.targetVM === this) // true
  }
 }
})
```

Comment: Starting from a dom element I'm trying to understand what is the vue component controlling that element (if any).

Answer (score -3):

Exactly what Kamil said,

```
element = this.$el
```

But make sure you don't have [fragment instances](https://vuejs.org/guide/components.html#Fragment-Instance).

Comment: Exactly what I commented to Kamil. This is not what the question asked.

Comment: if Kamil already answered that, then why the heck you provided the same answer?

Answer (score -4):

Since in Vue 2.0, no solution seems available, a clean solution that I found is to create a `vue-id` attribute, and also set it on the template. Then on `created` and `beforeDestroy` lifecycle these instances are updated on the global object.

Basically:

```
created: function() {
    this._id = generateUid();
    globalRepo[this._id] = this;
},

beforeDestroy: function() {
    delete globalRepo[this._id]
},

data: function() {
    return {
        vueId: this._id
    }
}
```

Comment: In vue 2 you use refs