# What is the Vue 3 equivalent of Vue 2's __vue__?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I see there's `__vueParentComponent` but I have to now say `__vueParentComponent.props.x` instead of `__vue__.x`. Also I can't see how I can access my custom variables (against the component instance) created in the `beforeCreate` method.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It looks like the following will give you access to everything you need:

```
__vueParentComponent.ctx
```

**Update:** This isn't available in production, however you can use the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47185136/155899). You basically create a [global mixin](https://vuejs.org/api/application.html#app-mixin) (which will be applied to every component). Then in the mounted event you store the instance against the element. For example:

```js
const app = Vue.createApp({ });

app.mixin({
    mounted() {
        this.$el.__vueComponent = this; // Or __vue__ for backwards compatibility.
    }
});
```