# Pass vue component to function

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am working on porting a project over to vue. I'm using muuri for a layout manager. However i need to use

```js
grid.add(itemElem, {
  layout: false,
  active: false
});
```

`itemElem` was an html element i created with `document.createElement` but that is a component now. How do i pass a component to the function?

I tried

```js
grid.add(<MyComponent />, {
  layout: false,
  active: false
});
```

However that doesn't work

I am using vue3 with options API

Comment: would [this question and its answers help](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26915193/522444)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Refs may help you along. https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-refs.html#ref-on-component

Then you could pass it to your function like:

```
grid.add(this.$refs.myComponent, {
  layout: false,
  active: false
});
```